# CKEDITOR : setData() causing Error for large Documents

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor a long time. But I'm facing some problem when trying

to load a large document using  `setData()` method.The problem is the data is not

setting to the editor(**editor is Empty**). What I'm done is,

1. Initialize Editor on when the page is loaded.

   ```
   <textarea id='editor1'></textarea>
   <script>
     var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');  
   </script>
   ```
2. At the same time I'm calling some function which will set the data like below.

   ```
   setData(data);
   function setData(data){
     CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(data);
   }
   ```

This will work on sometime but sometimes nothing is visible in the editor.

What am I doing wrong? Please, help me with this...

**Note:**

And there is no console error will be shown if the data is not setted to the document.

Comment: use a timeout function it might take some time to initiate or execute `setData` function in ckEditor on instance ready method

Comment: If the editor is not initialized then it will throw an error on editor.setData();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `CKEDITOR.replace(` with `instanceReady`

```
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
   on: {
          instanceReady: function( evt ) {
        // your stuff here
    }
   }
 });
```

or

try `CKEDITOR.inline(` with `instanceReady`

```
                CKEDITOR.inline('editor1', {                       
                    on: {
                        instanceReady: function () {
                }
             })
```